# SELECT DISTINCT rows

Tags: php, distinct

I am trying to output each of the rows by the value driver_profileId.

Currently this only outputs one value to the page. I am expecting a list of all the unique values in the cell.

Why is this not outputting more than one row?

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT(driver_profileId) FROM driver_profiles";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($row as $key) {
    echo $key;      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is because you're only fetching *one row*.  Try something more like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['driver_profileId'];
}
```

This will keep fetching rows until there are no more in the result set.  See the manual page for [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

> Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows for the resultset represented by the result parameter.

Comment: yes thats great. But it isnt returning some values. single digit values. Another question i know so thank you anyway!

Comment: No worries.  After this update you shouldn't need that `foreach` loop, so make sure you've taken that out.